# How to hide one side of the border of a TextField, in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, border, textfield

I am using the `TextField` widget, and I want to hide the left side border, as shown here:

[image: pic]

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 2.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 2.0),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
      ),
      hintText: 'User Name',
      hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person, size: 30.0, color: Colors.grey),
      errorText: snapshot.error),
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`borderRadius` can be specified only for uniform borders, that is, borders that have the same width and color for each side.

You can achieve a similar effect, by wrapping the `TextField` into a `Container` and making use of the `BoxShadow` property:

[image: example1]

Follows a full snippet of the screenshotted example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(2, 0),
                color: Colors.grey,
                spreadRadius: 0,
                blurRadius: 2,
              ),
            ],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(20),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
          child: TextField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: 'User Name',
              hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              suffixIcon: const Icon(
                Icons.person,
                size: 30.0,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    //
  }
}
```

---

A second, hackier, work-around, would be to use a `Stack` and a `Container` positioned to the far left to hide the left border. Although, in this case, it might be difficult to use a `Colors.transparent` background.
[image: example2]

Follows the full snippet:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 50,
          child: Stack(
            overflow: Overflow.visible,
            children: [
              TextField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  hintText: 'User Name',
                  hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  suffixIcon: const Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    size: 30.0,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: Container(
                  width: 20,
                  height: 50,
                  color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    //
  }
}
```

Comment: It is working but again if there's an error message it is appearing inside the container which shouldn't happen. Can't we do changes in the Textfield?

Comment: I've modified the answer supporting the `TextField` border, example number #2!

Answer (score 4):

**As of 2022** I'd like to add a solution using package [assorted_layout_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/assorted_layout_widgets):

### NonUniformOutlineInputBorder

Can be used to style **text-fields** and **containers**.

Similar to Flutter's native `OutlineInputBorder`, but you can hide some of the sides, by setting `hideTopSide`, `hideBottomSide`, `hideRightSide` and `hideLeftSide` to **true**.

Usage for text-fields:

```dart
TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
      enabledBorder: NonUniformOutlineInputBorder(hideLeftSide: true, ...),
      ...
```

Usage for containers:

```dart
Container(
   decoration: ShapeDecoration(
      shape: NonUniformOutlineInputBorder(
         hideLeftSide: true,
         borderSide: BorderSide(width: 10),
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(15),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(35),
         ),          
   ...
```

### NonUniformRoundedRectangleBorder

Can be used to style **buttons** and **containers**.

Similar to Flutter's native `RoundedRectangleBorder` but you can hide some of the sides, by setting `hideTopSide`, `hideBottomSide`, `hideRightSide` and `hideLeftSide` to **true**.

Usage for buttons:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
   style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      shape: NonUniformRoundedRectangleBorder(
         hideLeftSide: true,
         side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black87, width: 15.0),
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(15),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(35),
         ), 
      ...
```

Usage for containers:

```dart
Container(
   decoration: ShapeDecoration(
      shape: NonUniformRoundedRectangleBorder(...)),
   ...
```

*Note: I'm the author of that package.*

Answer (score 3):

You can change your `BoxDecoration`

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
   border: Border(
    left: BorderSide(width: 16.0, color: Colors.transparent),
    top: BorderSide(width: 16.0, color: Colors.lightBlue.shade900),
    right: BorderSide(width: 16.0, color: Colors.lightBlue.shade900),
    bottom: BorderSide(width: 16.0, color: Colors.lightBlue.shade900),
),
```

Comment: It is not working as BoxDecoration is applied to Container, not to Textfield.

Comment: one bracket was missing at the end, i added and it works for me

decoration: BoxDecoration(
   border: Border(
    left: BorderSide(width: 16.0, color: Colors.transparent),
    top: BorderSide(width: 16.0, color: Colors.lightBlue.shade900),
    right: BorderSide(width: 16.0, color: Colors.lightBlue.shade900),
    bottom: BorderSide(width: 16.0, color: Colors.lightBlue.shade900),
),)