# Add or remove specific borders of a Textfield

Tags: flutter, textfield

I want to remove the topBorder and keep the rest of the borders (leftBorder, rightBorder, bottomBorder) for a `Textfield`. Is there any way to do this? If it's not possible for `Textfield` then is it possible for `TextFormField` or any other similar widget?

[image: Image of the Textfield]

TextField used :-

```
TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: primaryColor)),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: primaryColor))),
              )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way to solve your problem is that,
You can wrap your textField with Container and assign the border to the container.
You can refer to below code

```
        Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border(
                  left: BorderSide(),
                  bottom: BorderSide(),
                  right: BorderSide(),
                ),
              ),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: I believe if you use this you will loose some of the functionality the border has. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputBorder-class.html For example it does not change color when it's selected

Answer (score 2):

I recommend checking out this package https://pub.dev/packages/assorted_layout_widgets. The author answered a similar question to yours here [How to hide one side of the border of a TextField, in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65342057/how-to-hide-one-side-of-the-border-of-a-textfield-in-flutter). Scroll to the bottom and you will see his answer.