# How to make clean non-uniforms side border on textfields

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

I want to reproduce this effect

[image: Non uniform border on left side of the textfield]

I have tried multiple solutions :

- [A borderRadius can only be given for uniform borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58812778/a-borderradius-can-only-be-given-for-uniform-borders) -> this one doesn't suits me because whenever you resize the widget, the area gets bigger
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72155716/21357698 -> this one is my last solution if there are no other solution because I would like to use native flutter without any package to do that.
- I've seen that flutter have added this recently but from my understanding it only works when the color is uniform between each side which is not my case : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/121921
- I have tried to add a BoxDecoration with a border only on left side that I wanted to round but i got the following error :

`A borderRadius can only be given on borders with uniform colors and styles.`

Linked code :

```dart
decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                left: BorderSide(width: 6, color: Colors.red),
              ),
              // borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
            ),
            child: pfTextField,
```

- I have tried to create my custom OutlineInputBorder so that i paint what i want but it just blink each time the view is rebuilt (if you have a solution to this it will suits me)

Here is the code i've done for this custom OutlineInputBorder :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class CustomInputBorder extends OutlineInputBorder {

  final Color? leftBorderSideColor;

  /// Constructeur
  const CustomInputBorder ({
    this.leftBorderSideColor,
    super.borderRadius,
    super.borderSide,
    super.gapPadding,
  });

  @override
  void paint(
    Canvas canvas,
    Rect rect, {
    double? gapStart,
    double gapExtent = 0.0,
    double gapPercentage = 0.0,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
  }) {
   
    RRect newRect = RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
      rect.left,
      rect.top,
      
      
      rect.left + 4,
      rect.bottom,
     
      topLeft: const Radius.circular(4),
      bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(4),
    );
    canvas.drawRRect(
      newRect,
      borderSide.toPaint()
        ..color = leftBorderSideColor ?? Colors.transparent
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill,
    );
    super.paint(
      canvas,
      rect,
      gapStart: gapStart,
      gapExtent: gapExtent,
      gapPercentage: gapPercentage,
      textDirection: textDirection,
    );
  }
}
```

I feel like i'm missing something, it must be a way to do it simply. Have you an idea on how i can achieve that or on what is my error on the last solution ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this without any package, I have solution and I think you have not tried that yet!
add a prefix Icon in decoration, I have not found a icon just like that but you can use an asset icon. I've rotated the most similar icon to help you out

```
TextFormField(
          controller: _textController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Enter Text',
            prefixIcon: Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: [
    Transform.rotate(
      angle: 90 * 3.141592653589793 / 180, // 90 degrees in radians
      child: Icon(
        Icons.linear_scale,
        color: Colors.orange,
      ),
    ),
  ], ),
```

),
),

[image]

this image will the first.
second make every thing custom

```
Center(
    child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Email-TextEmailField',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Card(
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: Container(
                  width: 5,
                  height: 40,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Enter Text',
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

this is 3rd and last most similar answer I got in my mind

```
 Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Email-TextEmailField',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.black, // Specify the border color
                width: 1.0, // Adjust the border width as needed
              ),// Adjust the radius as needed
            ),      
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Card(
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: Container(
                  width: 5,
                  height: 40,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter Text',
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  border: InputBorder.none, // Remove the border
                ),
              ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

[image]

if you have any question do a comment I will help you

Comment: These solutions doesn't suits me because it doesn't reproduice the effect given in my question. 
For each of these solutions, the colored part is not close enough to the border. It doesn't really work

Answer (score 2):

I wrote piece of craft code snippets for this custom text field. Hope it will fit for you. You can test it via [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=5db4faacea196ecfdcff799cf4e13763)

[image]

```
class CustomTextFieldWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomTextFieldWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        filled: true,
        prefixIcon: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.5),
              width: 4,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                ),
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        prefixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: 24,
          maxHeight: 58,
        ),
        hintText: "This is hint",
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            color: Colors.grey
        ),
        enabledBorder: getInputBorder(),
        focusedBorder: getInputBorder(),
        disabledBorder: getInputBorder(),
        errorBorder: getInputBorder(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
InputBorder getInputBorder() {
  return OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1,),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine Container border and TextField in Row to get the same effect.

Here is a sample you can refer to:

```
class EnterEmailWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const EnterEmailWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Enter email',
          style: GoogleFonts.aBeeZee(
            fontSize: 16.sp,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            color: const Color(0xFF1C283E),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 12.w),
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 48.w,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: const Color(0xFFD2D5D9), // Specify the border color here
                  width: 1, // Set the border width if desired
                ),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 3,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 8),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      style: GoogleFonts.aBeeZee(
                        fontSize: 13.sp,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'Enter email',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[Result](https://ibb.co/Qk6Nbc1)